# Undeletable Files and Folder

Tags: sd-card

So, I found an old SD Card of mine (2-3 years since last use) and when I open the SD Card, it had this folder containing some undeletable folders and files. At first, I tried reformatting the whole SD Card, but it didn't work, then I tried bundle deleting the apps, but once I replugged it in, all the files were back, like all the files that were deleted came back from the grave. The only ones I haven't managed to delete are these files, and I think they're the ones causing error. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

PS. I tried the reformatting it using windows explorer as well as disk partitioning and even CMD.

[image: Undeletable Folders and files]

Comment: The SD is dead so it's write-protected: it's a common failing mode for flash drives

Comment: So, there's no fix for the SD Card?

Comment: The only fix is the D3E harvest bin, then buying a newer one...if you consider it a fix. The flash drive reached its maximum number of writes. NOTE: If you want to "safetly clean" the drive a good remaining solution is the old friend capitan hammer and smashing it.